# Fish Shell - SVN log by user

Tags: shell, svn, fish

I want to make a custom function for displaying svn commits by user. Here is fish code for that.

```
function svn_log_by_user --description 'print svn commmits by user in current svn directory'
  svn log | sed -n "/$argv/,/-----$/p" | more
end
```

But it has error like the one below:

> fish: The '$' character begins a variable name. The character '/', which directly followed a '$', is not allowed as a part of a variable name, and variable names may not be zero characters long. To learn more about variable expansion in fish, type 'help expand-variable'.

Does anyone has idea for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's complaining about the line:

```
svn log | sed -n "/$argv/,/-----$/p" | more
                                ^here
```

You need to escape the second `$`, like so:

```
svn log | sed -n "/$argv/,/-----\$/p" | more
```